# Ruby: Resque queues instantly

Tags: ruby, web, redis, sinatra

I have the following code. Its job to is to send an email based on data given through the browser (using Sinatra). It sends an email to the address given after 20 seconds. When I run the program, It instantly sends the email, without waiting for the time. Can anyone help me out with this issue.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'pony'
require 'resque'
require 'resque_scheduler'
require 'active_support/time'

Resque.redis = 'localhost:6379'
Resque::Scheduler.dynamic = true

def sendMail

Pony.mail({
  :to => 'eldurotaduro@gmail.com',
  :via => :smtp,
  :via_options => {
    :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port                 => '587',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :user_name            => 'EMAIL',
    :password             => 'PASSWD',
    :authentication       => :plain, # :plain, :login, :cram_md5, no auth by default
    :domain               => "localhost.localdomain" # the HELO domain provided by the            client to the server
  },
   :body => 'roar'
})

end


class Roar
    def self.queue; :app; end
end

class ChildJob 

@message
@email

def setMess(mes)
    @message = mes
end

def setMail(mail)
    @email = mail
end


def self.queue; :app; sendMail; end

def self.perform
  Pony.mail({
  :to => 'eldurotaduro@gmail.com',
  :via => :smtp,
  :via_options => {
    :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port                 => '587',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :user_name            => 'EMAILHERE@gmail.com',
    :password             => 'PASSWD',
    :authentication       => :plain, # :plain, :login, :cram_md5, no auth by default
    :domain               => "localhost.localdomain" # the HELO domain provided by the client to the server
  },
   :body => 'HAHAH'
})
end

end



get '/:email/:message/:time' do

email = params[:email]
message = params[:message]
time = params[:time]
time = time.to_i

Resque.enqueue_in(20.seconds, ChildJob)

end
```

Comment: Isn't this line the problem? `def self.queue; :app; sendMail; end` It looks like you're trying to set the default queue, but actually you're running `sendMail` (`:app` does nothing).

Comment: But wont the `self.queue` method run whatevers inside in the queue?

Comment: `:app` is a symbol, what does that line do? Nothing. The _last_ line of a method is important as it's the return value, but because `sendMail` is the last line `:app` essentially does nothing.

Comment: so the solution for the problem would be to remove the `:app` symbol?

Comment: I don't use Resque, just Ruby, but reading the docs shouldn't `sendMail` be in [the perform method](https://github.com/resque/resque/tree/1-x-stable#overview)? (did you get the `self.queue` trick [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9283176/335847)? They've used `perform` too).

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `:app` symbol in `self.queue` as that's what sets the default queue (see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9283176/335847)). Put the `sendMail` into a `self.perform` method, as that's the thing you want done when the schedule is met. e.g.

```
def self.queue
  :app
end

def self.perform
  sendMail
end
```